# Python [Tkinter]: newline print when using return as a command

Tags: python, tkinter

Apologies if this is asked elsewhere, but I've been unable to find information on this.

Simply put, I've got a textbox with a function that when a button or return is pressed, will send the contents to another textbox and wipe the contents of the first textbox(NOTE: not using an entry variable due to the lack of wrapping possible). Essensially its a chat interface.

```
def __init__(self):
        #create chat window
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Setup()

    def run(self):
        self.Window.mainloop()

    def Setup(self):
        self.screen = Text(self.Window,
                             bg = BGtext,
                             fg = FGtext,
                             font = "sans-serif 12",
                             wrap = WORD,

        self.screen.configure(cursor="arrow")
        
        #widget for user to enter text
        #text used over entry to allow for wrapping
        self.messenger = Text(self.Window,
                              bg = BGtext,
                              fg = FGtext,
                              wrap = WORD,
                              font = "sans-serif 12")

        ...

        #auto focus on the entry message box when the window is active
        self.messenger.focus()
        #enter command functionality
        self.messenger.bind("<Return>", self.entermsg)
        #when escaped out, the program exits.
        self.messenger.bind("<Escape>", self.quit)
        #sendbutton coding 
        sendbutton = Button(self.messengerplace,
                                text = "Send",
                                font = "sans-serif 11 bold", 
                                width = 20,
                                bg = "#002654",
                                fg = "white",
                                command = lambda: self.entermsg(None))
```

Unfortunately when you press return to send the message to the chatlog, the message will send, wipe and add a newline to the box, meaning the user starts on the 2nd line. I'm looking for a way to make the return function work but prevent a newline from being created. It's a minor glitch but it is maddening to not know how to fix it.

I tried to truncate the code to the bare essensials but if more is needed, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Your event handler for the Return key needs to end with `return "break"`, to tell Tkinter not to further process the key event (in this case, by inserting it into the Text).

Comment: God I'm bad at this. Yeah that fixed it. Thank you.